# Confusion regarding term in taylor series expansion for dy/dx=f(h)

Tags: taylor-expansion

I start by considering a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(y), y(t_0)=y_0$ and using a step size of $\frac{h}{n}$ where h is any arbitrary constant.

The 1st step in Euler method will be

$y(t_0+\frac{h}{n})=y(t_0)+\frac{h}{n}f(y_0)$

The 2nd step with euler method

$y(t_0+\frac{h}{n}+\frac{h}{n})$

$=y(t_0+\frac{h}{n})+\frac{h}{n}f(y_0+\frac{h}{n}f)$

$=y(t_0)+\frac{h}{n}f(y_0)+\frac{h}{n}[f(y_0)+\frac{h}{n}ff'(y_0)+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{h}{n}f)^2f''(y_0)+...]$

$=y(t_0)+2\frac{h}{n}f+\frac{h^2}{n^2}ff'(y_0)+\frac{1}{2}((\frac{h}{n})^2f^2f''(y_0)+...$

3rd step

$y(t_0+\frac{h}{n}+\frac{h}{n}+\frac{h}{n})$

$=y(t_0)+2\frac{h}{n}f+\frac{h^2}{n^2}ff'(y_0)+\frac{1}{2}((\frac{h}{n})^2f^2f''(y_0)+\frac{h}{n}[f(y_0+\frac{2h}{n}f+\frac{h^2}{n^2}ff'+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{h}{n})^2f^2f''+...)]$

$=y(t_0)+2\frac{h}{n}f+\frac{h^2}{n^2}ff'(y_0)+\frac{h}{n}[f(y_0)+f'[2\frac{h}{n}f+\frac{h^2}{n^2}ff'(y_0)+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{h^2}{n^2})f^2f''+...]]$

I am confuse here,

Is the term $ff',f^2f'',f'f'f $ and so on will appear in taylor series? How to derive the term from $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the local error computation you only need to consider one step of step size $h$. Numerically, 
$$
y_1=y_0+h·f(y_0)
$$
and analytically
$$
y(t_0+h)=y(t_0)+y'(t_0)·h+\frac12 y''(t_0)·h^2+… = y_0+h·f(y_0)+\frac{h^2}{2}·f'(y_0)f(y_0)+\frac{h^3}6·\Bigl(f''(y_0)[f(y_0),f(y_0)]+f'(y_0)f'(y_0)f(y_0)\Bigr)+…
$$
so that the difference is, as expected, in the quadratic term.

For a systematic treatment of the derivative expressions for higher order methods one uses the rooted trees introduced by Butcher.